# How to get zopim livechat button's click event?

Tags: jquery

On click of the zopim button I have to open the chat window in different page in mobile.

Jquery

```
if (/Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile|Opera Mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent)) {
   $('.chatSection a').attr('href','javascript:$zopim.livechat.window.openPopout();');

$zopim(function() {
                $zopim.livechat.window.openPopout();
        });
}
```

On click of button I have opened the window in different page. Need click function of the `$zopim.livechat.button`

`$zopim.livechat.button.onClick` something like this.

Can anyone help me out.